# How to get APNS notification in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

Hello I am using APNS Server in fluter application for sending notification in IOS Device i Have Received notification in background or kill state , but in Foreground Notification is not receiving in my app.

Comment: Use can use flutter_local_notifications plugin to handle this scenario

Comment: yes i used but in background when i tap in notification its showing me 2 notification when i tap on it